# Custom 404 in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, twig, http-status-code-404, silex

Trying to have my own 404 error twig page on Silex, I'm having problems while I'm rendering the template. I guess should be an authentication problem, but can't find where and what :/

This is my app.php:

```
use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

// 404 - Page not found
$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
      return $app['twig']->render('error.html.twig', array(
        'code' => '404',
      ));
    }

    $code = ($e instanceof HttpException) ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500;
    return $app['twig']->render('error.html.twig', array(
      'code' => $code,
    ));
});
```

But I get the same error:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException' with message 'The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.' in /var/www/vhosts/dogsupdate.com/backend.dogsupdate.com/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:57

The point is that if I return a json error, it works:

```
// 404 - Page not found
$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return $app->json(array('error' => 'Page Not Found'), 404);
    }

    $code = ($e instanceof HttpException) ? $e->getStatusCode() : 500;
    return $app->json(array('error' => $e->getMessage()), $code);
});
```

Comment: Do you use `user` in templates? Add the code of `error.html.twig` and `layout` if it is used.

Comment: ummm no, how could I use it? sounds like my solution, but damn, i'm getting crazy with this simple thing.

Comment: try returning a Response with the html as content. also you could attach your error.html.twig